# c# force compiling a program with errors, ignoring the errors

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, reference, compilation

I am wondering if there's a way to force ms vs 2010 c# to compile the program I made, since I have 2 dlls with the same name to be used with, using assembly resolve I am able to interchange the other but the thing is both dll have different methods and depending on the level I gave it will execute the unique method the dll has. I can make use of dynamic type but are there any other way to tell ms vs 2010 to force compile when there's an error?

Say dll1 has method A and dll2 has method B, when coding I say `if(condition) classname.A else classname.B`, but reference only to dll1, making the use of `classname.B` an error. So how do I force compile this? Or do I just keep on using dynamic type?

Comment: What do you expect the compiler to do when you tell it to compile something that it does not understand?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't force a compile with errors. Some sort of dynamic approach is your only way, e.g. reflection or the `dynamic` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This approach really "[smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)." To start, no, you can't ignore errors like that.

There are so many approaches that would be more reasonable. Just to name a few: Using `dynamic`, having `classname` in both dll1 and dll2 derive from the same base class or implement the same interface, using something like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx).

Some of those may be overkill for your solution. I just wonder if maybe you're asking us how to fix a symptom rather than asking us for help with the actual root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because even if the class has the same name in A.dll and B.dll, it is still not the same class. So even if you somehow managed to compile it, and switch out the dll, the program would still probably crash.

As others have said, use dynamic or reflection.